# Is the iii chord in second inversion ever used?

Tags: chord-inversions

In A major if I want to harmonize a descending step bassline that goes A>G#>F#>E>A I could be looking at:

I iii6/4 vi V I

I am not sure about that iii6/4 chord though. Is this ever used? Could anyone share any beginner to intermediate examples of this chord to analyze how they are used in voice leading and if and why it may be avoided?

Comment: If you play it, does it sound good? If so then use it. If not, maybe not. Whether it’s been done before is less of a valuable guide to whether to do it now

Comment: Don't know, I am studying voice leading so I would like to see how it is written and voice led. How it sounds now is less important

Answer (score 2):

I'll let a music theorist speak to it, but it seems to me that there are some benefits to it. My first impulse would probably to harmonize that G# with V6:

```
X:1
L:1/2
K:A
[Ace] [GBe] | [FAc] [EAc]
```

... but your iii6/4 keeps the other two chord members in common from the I chord (C# and E). This could be a good thing, making the motion from I to iii smoother. On the other hand, the B in the 1st-inversion V above smooths the motion in parallel thirds all the way from I to V6 to vi. On the other other hand, the second measure below echoes the motion of the first measure, keeping two members in common between vi and V. And all of this could probably be improved by using four-part chords and giving some thought to the voicing.

```
X:1
L:1/2
K:A
[Ace] [Gce] | [FAc] [EAc]
```

Answer (score 2):

For a bass of `^1 ^7 ^6 ^5` I think a common way to harmonize it is `I V6 V43/V V`.

In relation to your recent question about passing `6/4` chords you get the passing `6/4` motion over the `V` chord.

Another progression for that bass is a "falling thirds" type sequence `[I V6][vi iii6]`.

Neither are examples of `iii6/4`, but your question really seems to be more about how to harmonize a descending bass.

Answer (score 2):

<s>I suppose iii6/4 could be used as a pedal 6/4, surrounded by vi chords.  That's about the only place where it's actually likely to occur idiomatically in "classical" style.</s>  (If you believe in arpeggiated 6/4 chords, then I also suppose one could see a iii6/4 there.)

(EDIT: Oops -- I just realized I was thinking about the wrong context for pedal 6/4.  A iii6/4 would have to occur between minor vii chords, which are not diatonic to any key.  So no, iii6/4 doesn't really exist there.)

As a passing 6/4, you might perhaps see a 6/4 interpolated between vi and vi6.  But in classical style, that's more likely to turn into a V6/4 of vi rather than iii6/4.

As Michael Curtis notes, there are much better and more idiomatic ways of harmonizing a descending scalar bass line.  Using iii6/4, though technically following the "rules" of voice-leading, wouldn't be idiomatic.